# Dynamic routes being added to router but don't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an application in angular 6 which upon login takes the user to the main page. This page contains multiple links on both the navbar at the top (called `toolbar`) and the side bar on the left (called `side-nav`). I have created a custom dynamic routing service that would add links and their labels for the html templates.

The paths are added to the router using `router.config.unshift`, and I have verified that these paths are added properly under `config` when I log the router in the console.

The login page of my application has the root path (i.e `' '`) and the `Main` page after login has the path `/main` (router configuration added below).

The problem I seem to be having has 2 parts:

1. whenever I click a link on the `side-nav` or the `toolbar`, the url on the address bar shows me `localhost.com:4200/main/<path>` and the page displayed is the `NotFoundComponent` (i.e it could not find the route). I don't want the path to be a `child` of `/main` but the root url (i.e `' '`), because the navigation bar would be on every page, and this might bring up a situation like `localhost:4200/main/<path>/<anotherpath>/<someotherpath>/<path>` on clicking multiple items, which a is **pretty** bad design.
2. If i try to manually add the path to the application eg. `localhost:4200/<path>` the same result is shown (`NotFoundComponent`). No matter what I do it simply cannot find the path, even though in console it's perfectly defined when I log the router.

For testing purposes all my paths redirect me to a `DummyComponent`.

Here is my code, I am sharing the code for my `ToolbarComponent`, and the Side Nav is pretty much the same except for a few bits and pieces:

**app.routing.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { LoginComponent } from 'src/app/views/login/login.component';
import { MainComponent } from 'src/app/views/main/main.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from 'src/app/services/auth-guard/auth-guard.service';
import { NotFoundComponent } from 'src/app/views/error/not-found/not-found.component';
/**
* Contains a list of routes to enable navigation from one view to the next
* as users perform application tasks
* @property {array} routes
*/
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**dynamic-routing.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
/*
* This service will provide components with the ability to dynamically create
* routes within the application
*/
export class DynamicRoutingService {

  /*
  * Array for storing links
  *
  */
  private links = new Array<{ text: string, path: string, icon: string }>();

  constructor(private translate: TranslatePipe) { }

  /*
  * Method to fetch data
  *
  */
  getLinks() {
    if (this.links.length != 0) {
      return this.links;
    }
    else {
      throw new Error(this.translate.transform("generic[responses][error][404][002]"));
    }
  }

  /*
  * Method to store data
  *
  */
  addItem({ text, path, icon = null }) {
    try {
      this.links.push({ text: text, path: path, icon: icon });
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(this.translate.transform("generic[responses][error][400]"));
    }
  }

  /*
  * Method to remove a specific link
  *
  */
  removeItem({ text }) {
    if (this.links.length != 0) {
      this.links.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.text === text) {
          this.links.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error (this.translate.transform('generic[resposnes][error][404][002]'));
    }
  }

  /*
  * Remove all links from the array
  */
  clearAll() {
    this.links.length = 0;
  }
}
```

**toolbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';
import { DynamicRoutingService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-routing/dynamic-routing.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DummyComponent } from 'src/app/views/dummy/dummy.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss'],
  providers: [DynamicRoutingService]
})

/**
* This component renders the Toolbar UI
*
*/
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  /**
  * Object containing the translated names and their respective icons
  * @property {array} links
  */
  links: Array<{ text: string, path: string }>;

  /**
  * constructor for toolbar component is responsible for initializing translatePipe, dynamic routing and router,
  * as well as adding routes dynamically to the router and the dynamicRouting service
  * @param translate
  * @param router
  * @param dynamicRouting
  *
  */
  constructor(private translate: TranslatePipe, private router: Router, private dynamicRouting: DynamicRoutingService) {
    this.router.config.unshift(
      { path: 'knowledge-base', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: DummyComponent }
    );
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "home", path: "home" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "knowledge_base", path: "knowledge-base" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "settings", path: "settings" });
  }

  /**
  * Upon initialization this function fetches the links and inserts the translated
  * text and path to be used by the template
  *
  * @param
  * @return
  */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = [];
    let rawData = this.dynamicRouting.getLinks();
    let self = this;
    rawData.forEach(function(data) {
      let text = self.translate.transform("generic[toolbar][categories][" + data.text + "][label]");
      self.links.push({ text: text, path: data.path });
    });
  }

}
```

**toolbar.component.html**

```
<app-header
  [fixed]="true"
  [navbarBrandFull]="{src: 'assets/logo.png', width: 143, height: 36, alt: 'RT Logo'}"
  [navbarBrandMinimized]="{src: 'assets/logo2.png', width: 35, height: 35, alt: 'RT Logo'}"
  [sidebarToggler]="'lg'">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-md-down-none" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li class="nav-item px-3" *ngFor="let link of links">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="link.path">{{ link.text }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
  </ul>
</app-header>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) which shows the problem?

Comment: Could you please try resetConfig Method by passing new routes by constructing with existing routes instead of mutating routes config object

Comment: Hi @AbineshDevadas, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @coreuter apologies I'm not very good at stackblitz. I will try to recreate the problem if i can but I feel my application is too tightly coupled to reproduce an isolated error

Comment: @noobdev, instead of modifying router.config using unshift, create a new array with your dynamic route config & static route.config then use router.resetConfig(<newly created Routes>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**: The problem lied in my template: the value passed to `routerLink` needed to be modified, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896308/angular-2-add-routerlink-in-child-which-points-to-root-router) and [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139850/refer-to-link-path-while-redirecting-to-root-using-routerlink)