# Refer to "link.path" while redirecting to root using [routerLink]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application that uses a typescript file for setting up links and within the template I use `ngFor` to interpolate through the links and build a navigation bar. Within those link objects there is a property called `link.path` containing the path to be redirected to. I use `[routerLink]` to redirect to the path required, which works fine, but I was not at the root url. I need to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896308/angular-2-add-routerlink-in-child-which-points-to-root-router) functionality, which appends the child route to the root of the application. However, after changing my implementation to:

`[routerLink]= '["/link.path"]'`

On click I am redirected to `<URL>/link.path` rather than `<URL>/<name under link.path>` which naturally gives me a not found error.

how do i change my expression above to show the actual value inside this parameter rather than giving me `link.path` as a string?

**component.ts**

```
// imports, declarations of classes and other stuff.

  * @property {array} links
  */
  links: Array<{ text: string, path: string }>;

  /**
  * constructor for toolbar component is responsible for initializing translatePipe, dynamic routing and router,
  * as well as adding routes dynamically to the router and the dynamicRouting service
  * @param translate
  * @param router
  * @param dynamicRouting
  *
  */
  constructor(private translate: TranslatePipe, private router: Router, private dynamicRouting: DynamicRoutingService) {
    this.router.config.unshift(
      { path: 'knowledge-base', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: DummyComponent }
    );
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "home", path: "home" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "knowledge_base", path: "knowledge-base" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "settings", path: "settings" });
  }
  /**
  * Upon initialization this function fetches the links and inserts the translated
  * text and path to be used by the template
  *
  * @param
  * @return
  */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = [];
    let rawData = this.dynamicRouting.getLinks();
    let self = this;
    rawData.forEach(function(data) {
      let text = self.translate.transform("generic[toolbar][categories][" + data.text + "][label]");
      self.links.push({ text: text, path: data.path });
    });

  //rest of the methods
```

**html**

```
<app-header
  [fixed]="true"
  [navbarBrandFull]="{src: 'assets/logo.png', width: 143, height: 36, alt: 'RT Logo'}"
  [navbarBrandMinimized]="{src: 'assets/logo2.png', width: 35, height: 35, alt: 'RT Logo'}"
  [sidebarToggler]="'lg'">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-md-down-none" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li class="nav-item px-3" *ngFor="let link of links">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/link.path"]'>{{ link.text }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
  </ul>
</app-header>
```

Comment: try using `[routerLink]='["/{{link.path}}"]'`

Comment: Nope, that causes an interpolation error.

Comment: try using `routerLink = "/{{link.path}}"`

Comment: `routerLink` accept array then you can try: `[routerLink]='[ "/", link.path ]'` separate string from variable

Comment: Works! Can you post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @noobdev added answer with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular you can compose URL with respect of any path; `[routerLink]` provide the facility to provide string token or variables to make final path

> `[routerLink]="['/', var, 'str']"` = `/var/str`

```html
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/", link.path]'>{{ link.text }}</a>
```

Angular official reference for RouterLink : https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink