# How to manipulate routerLink when using app-sidebar-nav in coreUI?

Tags: angular, typescript, core-ui

I am using CoreUI's `app-sidebar-nav` (link [here](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-angular/tree/master/projects/coreui/angular/src/lib/sidebar)) for redirecting to various parts of my application. However, the child route is appended to the current url instead of appending to the root of the application.

I had a similar issue with the toolbar in the same application which was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896308/angular-2-add-routerlink-in-child-which-points-to-root-router) (after a few modifications mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139850/refer-to-link-path-while-redirecting-to-root-using-routerlink)), but in this case I am using a CoreUI template, and wanted to know if there was a way I could manage to manipulate the routerLink the same way I am able to manipulate in my toolbar. [this](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-angular/blob/b924a8d11fc231a2ac2e980b50d4ac0a69cdd65b/projects/coreui/angular/src/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-link.component.html) might be of some help to determine where the `routerLink` resides

Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { navItems } from 'src/app/views/core/side-nav/_nav';
/**
* This component renders the UI of the side-nav component.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav',
  templateUrl: './side-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav.component.scss']
})
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {
  /**
  * The constructor initializes the navItems meta.
  */
  constructor(private nav: navItems) { }
  /**
  * This property comprises the navItems meta.
  */
  public navItems = this.nav.exportData();
  /**
  * This flag indicates wether the sidebar is minimized or not.
  */
  public sidebarMinimized = true;
  /**
  * This property is an eventlistener.
  */
  private changes: MutationObserver;
  /**
  * This property contains the document body.
  */
  public element: HTMLElement = document.body;

  /**
  * This method observes the changes in the DOM, and minimizes and maximizes the
  * side nav accordingly.
  */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      this.sidebarMinimized = document.body.classList.contains('sidebar-minimized');
    });
    this.changes.observe(<Element>this.element, {
      attributes: true
    });
  }

}
```

**navitems ts file**

```
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicRoutingService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-routing/dynamic-routing.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DummyComponent } from 'src/app/views/dummy/dummy.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from 'src/app/views/logout/logout.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

/**
* The purpose of this class is to provide an object containing the translated names
* for the categories in the nav bar, based on the translation file found in assets/i18n
*
* @class navItems
*/
export class navItems {

  /**
  * Object containing the translated names and their respective icons
  * @property {array} navData
  */
  navData: Array<{ name: string, url: string, icon: string }>;

  /**
  * constructor for toolbar component is responsible for initializing translatePipe, dynamic routing and router,
  * as well as adding routes dynamically to the router and the dynamicRouting service
  * @param translate
  * @param router
  * @param dynamicRouting
  *
  */
  constructor(private translate: TranslatePipe, private router: Router, private dynamicRouting: DynamicRoutingService) {
    this.router.config.unshift(
      { path: 'knowledge-base', component: DummyComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent}
    );
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "home", path: "home", icon: "icon-drop" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "knowledge_base", path: "knowledge-base", icon: "icon-pencil" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "profile", path: "profile", icon: "icon-puzzle" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "settings", path: "settings", icon: "icon-cursor" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "logout", path: "logout", icon: "icon-arrow-left-circle" });
  }

  /**
  * When called this method sets the required data into the navData object
  * @param
  * @method exportData
  * @return
  */
  exportData() {
    this.navData = [];
    let rawData = this.dynamicRouting.getLinks();
    let self = this;
    rawData.forEach(function(data) {
      let text = self.translate.transform("generic[nav_bar][categories][" + data.text + "][label]");
      self.navData.push({ name: text, url: data.path, icon: data.icon });
    });
    return this.navData;
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<app-sidebar [fixed]="true" [display]="'lg'">
  <app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems" [perfectScrollbar] [disabled]="sidebarMinimized"></app-sidebar-nav>
  <app-sidebar-minimizer class="custom-padding-bottom"></app-sidebar-minimizer>
</app-sidebar>
```